# Detecting when a ThreadPool user work item gets cleaned up

Tags: .net, multithreading, clr, threadpool

It is my understanding that anything running using .NETs threadpool like this:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(myproc);
```

will get terminated cleanly by the CLR when the application is closed down.

Let's say in this case that the myproc function contains an infinite loop. Is there a way I can hook into the termination of the thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  When the CLR is tearing down your process, it aggressively aborts any remaining background threads.  I say *aggressively* aborts because, unlike a normal call to `Thread.Abort()`, no exception is raised in your code, so you have no way to respond to it.

At this point, the CLR doesn't particularly care if you have anything left to do; your process is dead, kaput, and about to be buried, and there's nothing you can do to stop it.  If something is important enough that it *absolutely must be cleaned up* before the process terminates, it should go in a foreground thread so that the process will stay around long enough for it to do whatever it needs to do.